# Is docker session data persistent / shared with subsequent instances?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm very new to containers/docker and it is absolutely changing my life so far however I have one question I'm not really finding a solid answer on. I apologize in advance if this qeustion too basic / silly :)

In my Node app I use a queue to spawn a Docker instance with a browser to screenshot some pages before terminating the docker instance and process the next item in the queue (eventually will process several items concurrently).

In my Dockerfile I added the COPY command to create a static copy of my codebase which is used in the Docker instance, including the chrome browser etc.

If I view say 100,000 pages the browsers cache would build up so my question is, does docker create a fresh version of the data used in the COPY command for every instance launched? I know I can clear the browsers cache on launch etc, but I'm more curious to know whether or not every launch is an original vanilla copy of the initial build, so nothing is shared/cached with subsequent launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every run is vanilla copy of initial build. If you require data to be persistent, you can use volumes. Check this official guide for more information: [Manage data in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)

Comment: Thank-you! I assumed this was the case but wanted to be sure.